# Multiple Marker Listeners

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I'm working with google maps javascript api, marker listener.
When I click on marker infowindow should pop up.
In for loop I'm adding multiple(3 in this example) markers.
Here is the code:

```
       for (z = 0; z < 3; z++) {
            arrMarkers.push( new google.maps.Marker({
            position: flightPlanCoordinates[arrCoords.length-1],
            map: map, title: 'Kraj', clickable: true
            }));        

            arrInfoWindow.push( new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: 'Hello world'
            }));

            google.maps.event.addListener(arrMarkers[z], 'click', function() {
                    arrInfoWindow[z].open(map, arrMarkers[z]);
            });
       }
```

Infowindows don't pop up.

Comment: I found solution, replace: arrInfoWindow[z].open(map, arrMarkers[z]); with arrInfoWindow[z].open(map, this)

Answer (score 0):

you can not push a info windows on arrInfoWindow, it's need to be separate
try this

```
for (z = 0; z < 3; z++) 
{
  arrMarkers.push( new google.maps.Marker({
  position: flightPlanCoordinates[arrCoords.length-1],
  map: map, title: 'Kraj', clickable: true
  }));        

  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: 'Hello world'
  });
  arrInfoWindow.push( infoWindow );

  google.maps.event.addListener(arrMarkers[z], 'click', function() {
          arrInfoWindow[z].open(map, arrMarkers[z]);
  });
}
```